# Search letters in a text file Python

Tags: python

I was wondering if someone could help me. I'm a beginner in Python. What I want to do is to type any letters and the program has to find them in a text file with a list of objects. It has to print the object that contains all the letters in no order specific.
For example, I have a text file with 5 words:

```
yellow
morning
sea
soiberg
sand
```

I want the program to show all the words that contain the letters `"goi"`.

Result:

```
morning
soiberg
```

What I have at this moment is this:

```
with open('d:\lista.txt', 'r') as inF:
   l = input("Buscar: ")
   for line in inF:
       if l[0] in line:
          if l[1] in line:
              if l[2] in line:
                 print(line)
```

But what if I want to find only 2 letters or 5 or 7. I don't know what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all):

```
with open(r'd:\lista.txt', 'r') as inF:
    l = input("Buscar: ")
    for line in inF:
        if all(c in line for c in l)
          #code
```

Examples:

```
>>> strs = "goi"
>>> line = "morning"
>>> all(c in line for c in strs)
True
>>> line = "soiberg"
>>> all(c in line for c in strs)
True
>>> line = "sea"
>>> all(c in line for c in strs)
False
```

Note that you should use raw string for windows file paths, otherwise something like `'\t'` in your file path will be converted to a tab space and you'll get an error.

```
r'd:\lista.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for using a set and building a generator over matching line, then iterating over that:

```
with open('input') as fin:
    letters = set(raw_input('Buscar: '))
    matches = (line for line in fin if not letters.difference(line.strip())
    for match in matches:
        # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way by using simple tools:

```
with open(r'd:\lista.txt', 'r') as inF:
    l = input("Buscar: ")
    for line in inF:
        counter=0
        for letter in l:
            if letter in line:
                counter+=1
        if counter==len(l):
            print(line)
```